# "cant set headers once they are sent" for no reason, not using .next() Nodejs

Tags: node.js, header, jsonp, sequelize.js

Im losing my hair over this! i keep getting the "cant set headers after they are sent" error, im sure im not calling Next() as i saw in the other questions. My code was working until i tried to do some refactoring, i didnt change anything is this class, so i dont know whats causing it. Other questions say it because i try to set the header after calling writeHead, but i only call it once and then write the body.

The worst part is that it was working before! here is the code

```
DataBase.prototype.execute = function execute(type, query, response, parameters) {  

    this.sequelize = new Sequelize('inmobiliaria', 'root', 'root',
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        dialect: 'mysql'
    }
);
//this.users.logIn(response.post['user'], response.post['pass']);



/*
from the sequelize docs:
Options is an object with the following keys:
    {
      logging: console.log, // a function (or false) for logging your queries
      plain: false,         // if plain is true, then sequelize will return all of the records within an array, otherwise it will return a single object/first record returned.
      raw: true            // Set this to true if you don't have a model definition for your query
    }
*/
var options = { raw: true };

var result = this.sequelize.query(query, null, options, parameters)
.success(function (rows) {        
    if (type == 'select') {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });           
        response.write(parameters.callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(rows) + ')');//wrap the json inside the callback function to make a jsonp
        response.end();
    } else if (type == 'modify') {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.write('Query was successful');
        response.end();
    }
}
).error(function (e) {
    console.log('An error occured: ', e);
    response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    response.write('There was an error man, shits on fire yo ---> ' + e);
    response.end();
}
);
```

}

The error appears on the first line with the response.writeHead()
You can see im not using .next() or anything too fancy, and think the order of the calls is right. No other class is modifying this at the moment, this is where i query the db and write the result in order to return it. im using manual queries because my db an queries are complicated and i prefer to use sql.

Comment: The error comes from the second place you set headers, so you need to track down the first place, which does not appear to be in this section of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in another class i had some test code that did write the headers again as suggested by Aaron. Guess the late night code played its part, thanks for reading anyway.